# Java class super query

Tags: java, android, class

really silly question here. I know how classes and inhertiance work but I've been doing some `android` programming and have managed to confuse myself a little on the super class declaration

The following code implements the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. Now as far as I'm concerned this is the super class. Are the variables being sent to satisfy the super class rather than inheriting from it?

Obviously i was always under the impression that the super class references the super class variables to use in another class.

code:

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, KEY_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

Comment: what is your exact question ??

Comment: Is the 'super' declaration being used here to inherit from the 'SQLiteOpenHelper' class......or has it been used to satisfy the required variable objects of the 'SQLiteOpenHelper' class.

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question - it is not very clear - you don't understand what this:

```
super(context, KEY_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

means.

Well, it is the only way to call the superclass' constructor. Most of the time, the superclass in question has a constructor that has no arguments, so then the call to the superclass' constructor may be omitted. But if it has no such constructor, or you want to call another constructor which does need some arguments you need to use this. Note: a call to `super()` should always be the first statement in your constructor, because otherwise the superclass would not yet exist when your constructor is being called, which could lead to very nasty, very unpredictable behaviour. (And the Java engineers are aware of that, so calling `super()` too late or omitting it when it is not allowed you'll get a compile-time error.)

Answer (score 0):

You're extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`, not implementing it, as you would an interface. Calling `super(...)`, you're indeed passing the arguments to the super constructor.

Comment: Thank you wulfgar! Thats all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

DBHelper is the sub-class, SQLiteOpenHelper is the super class. DBHelper is calling the super-Constructor in creating the instance. To do this, the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper is used, which needs some parameters to initialize variables in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

AS per your code statments, SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor should have four parameters otherwise compile time error.

And ofcourse if there are same variable in parent & child class and object reference of super class then that object will refer only super class varibales.

Hope now your doubts is clear !!!

Comment: Indeed they are Thank you Manoj!

Answer (score 0):

The super(context, KEY_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) means those variables getting sent in will be used for the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper. If you're extending that class, it could be that those variables are needed in order for it to be created properly.

In your own extended class constructor or method is where you do your own thing, but you seem to know that :P

Comment: Haha! I always feel silly when I end up answering alongside several others :P